# Bytes getting stuck in TCP RECV (pika and rabbitmq app)

Tags: python, tcp, rabbitmq, pika

We've been dealing with an issue where bytes are getting stuck in TCP RECV (see output below) when we send data through Pika to a rabbitmq exchange. Any thoughts? We're seeing 8 bytes, then 16 bytes after a while. Has anyone ran into a similar issue?

We've so far upped the TCP buffer sizes, rabbitmq memory sizes (watermark set at 0.95) and think we've finally tracked it down to the bottleneck being in tcp. We have about 80,000 messages which go through just fine, but the last few hundred (~4-500) will just trickle in every minute or so (from around 400m/s).

Any thoughts or pointers would be helpful.

```
tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:5672             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      634/beam
tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:15672            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      634/beam
tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:55672            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      634/beam
tcp    0  0 111.111.111.111:15672    222.222.222.222:60329   ESTABLISHED 634/beam
tcp    0  0 111.111.111.111:5672     111.111.111.111:49479   ESTABLISHED 634/beam
tcp    0  0 111.111.111.111:5672     111.111.111.111:49477   ESTABLISHED 634/beam
tcp    0  0 111.111.111.111:5672     111.111.111.111:49482   ESTABLISHED 634/beam
tcp    0  0 111.111.111.111:15672    222.222.222.222:60619   ESTABLISHED 634/beam
tcp    0  0 111.111.111.111:15672    222.222.222.222:60620   ESTABLISHED 634/beam
tcp    0  0 111.111.111.111:15672    222.222.222.222:60621   ESTABLISHED 634/beam
tcp    0  0 111.111.111.111:15672    222.222.222.222:60622   ESTABLISHED 634/beam
tcp    0  0 111.111.111.111:15672    222.222.222.222:60460   ESTABLISHED 634/beam
tcp   16  0 111.111.111.111:49482    111.111.111.111:5672    ESTABLISHED 963/python26
tcp   16  0 111.111.111.111:49479    111.111.111.111:5672    ESTABLISHED 957/python26
tcp    0  0 111.111.111.111:49477    111.111.111.111:5672    ESTABLISHED 949/python26
```

Versions:

```
Python 2.6.8
CentOS release 5.8 (Final)
RabbitMQ version 3.2.2
```

Edit: we played around with the socket timeouts and it seemed to affect the frequency that it happens, but it still goes to a trickle.

Comment: Maybe the [Flow Control](http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html) is the problem? If your RabbitMQ on debian see ulimit-related recomendations at http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html. I have far more active messages flow (10M+ in queues, 2k+/s flow) without any problems.

Comment: We're on CentOS and have already checked Flow Control - its triggered, then clears.

Comment: Can you update your Q with software versions info you are using (incl. kernel version) and way you installed it? I have both CentOS and Debian machines with RabbitMQ (some of them are a bit outdated), but I can't reproduce the issue you have. Thou, the problem is quite interesting.

Comment: Edited with python, centos and rabbitmq versions. We're using non-blocking pika connections and have tried blocking without success.

Comment: Perhaps Pika has a buffer.  What happens if you send a few commands, then close Pika's connection -- do all the commands happen immediately?